Pytest reportportal log is logging lots of unwanted/unspecified debug logs
So I see in debug level in my rp logs, lots of random stuff which I assume are from other libraries that use logger:
DEBUG | Starting new HTTPS connection (1): some_host.com:443 | _new_conn:1051

I tried many approaches, clearing handlers, creating specific logger with name, still does not work at all, those random logs are still added:
def setup_rp_logger():
    rp_logger = logging.getLogger('pytest_reportportal')

    # Remove any existing handlers
    for handler in rp_logger.handlers:
        rp_logger.removeHandler(handler)

    # Set up the logger with the custom handler
    rp_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    custom_handler = CustomRPLogHandler()
    rp_logger.addHandler(custom_handler)

    # Prevent propagation to root logger
    rp_logger.propagate = False

    return rp_logger


# Create and set up the Report Portal logger
rp_logger = setup_rp_logger()

I add rp config as follows:
config._inicache["rp_api_key"] = os.environ['RPID']
config._inicache["rp_endpoint"] = "some addrs"
config._inicache["rp_log_format"] = "%(levelname)s | %(message)s | %(funcName)s:%(lineno)s"
config._inicache["rp_project"] = "smthin"
config._inicache["rp_launch"] = config.getoption("--run_details")

I run rp with pytest --reportportal
Any idea on how to deal with this?
So after further investigation, it seems report portal is receiving all logs from standard python logging class:
        standard_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        standard_logger.info("This should not go to Report Portal")

Which I m not sure on how to disable

So problem seems to be with python standard logger, rp is somehow picking these up during pytest exec and thus causing them to show in rp logger on debug level
        standard_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)         standard_logger.info("This should not go to Report Portal")

You can set the info level in specific libraries. This is my logger setup in conftest.py for example (I use it from pytest_sessionstart)
def __setup_logger():
    for name in ['urllib3.connectionpool', 'selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection', 'reportportal_client.client', __name__]:
        logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    logging.setLoggerClass(RPLogger)
    return logger

